# Wysiwyg editor for angular4

Tags: angular, wysiwyg

Does someone knows a good free wysiwyg editor compatible with angular 4 ?

Froala seems to be good but unfortunately it's not free.

Maybe using angular 4 was not a good idea because it's hard to find a lot of basic things ...

Thank you

Comment: [wysihtml](https://github.com/Voog/wysihtml) is a good option with no dependency on JQuery and an MIT license.

Comment: The quality of all the answer is very good and they're very helpful. A pity the question has been closed, It's a case where a strict application of the rule made the StackOverflow less valuable...

Comment: CKEditor 5 has an official integration with Angular 2+. For an installation instruction check https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html The editor is Open Source, commercial license with support is available too.

Comment: best editor https://blog.almightytricks.com/2020/10/19/ngx-quill-free-wysiwyg-editor/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Since I had the same problem, I'm sharing the results of my research here:

## **[ng2-ckeditor](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor)**

demo [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/hnB0R3/)

[image]

## [ngx-editor](https://github.com/Sibiraj-S/ngx-editor)

demo [here](https://ngx-editor.stackblitz.io/)
[image]

## [quill.js for angular](https://github.com/surmon-china/ngx-quill-editor)

demo [here](https://surmon-china.github.io/ngx-quill-editor/)

Note: Quill uses JSON to store the data internally, not html.

[image]

## PRIME NG

Theme collection, that features a Quill-based WYSIWYG-editor as well, demo [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/editor). Some of themes are free.

## [ngx-md](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-md)

A WYSIWYG editor which uses MarkDown rather than HTML, demo [here](https://dimpu.github.io/ngx-md/)

**Edit**

If your choice was quill.js, you might want to use [KillerCodeMonkey's implementation](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill) since it is compatible with angular 5.

Comment: this answer may be useful to one, but can you suggest how to provide code editor itself? I mean i want a editor where i can write code and also side by side i can see code snippet in <pre> tag.

Comment: ngx-editor is not actively maintained

Comment: @AnilVangari thx I'll update it

Comment: To save somebody some time, quill does not currently work with Angular Universal, although it is my favorite in the bunch...

Comment: Is there any way to browse image in the `ng2-ckeditor`?

Comment: I also agree with quill.js solution. There is a very useful video tutorial on this:
https://youtu.be/mav4qhcaPqo

Answer (score 36):

Try this simple but powerful WYSIWYG editor for Angular 6-13 (native)

### [AngularEditor](https://github.com/kolkov/angular-editor)

Note: This native Angular 6+ WYSIWYG editor was created as library.

[image: ![AngularEditor]

Demo is [here](https://angular-editor-wysiwyg.stackblitz.io/)

PR or new features request are welcome.

This editor was originally created as part of my corporate project https://online.freicon.ru/, but I extracted it into separate library and post as open source project. I hope this helps someone solve their problems.

Comment: For some reason, the alignment of the controls is broken on a fresh implementation. I thought it was because of the base rem size of my document, but that was not the case. Any ideas?

Comment: @snkv Perhaps the base font is different, you need to understand ... the page with a working example. [link](https://angular-editor-wysiwyg.stackblitz.io/). In general, of course the styles and markings I still need to edit.

Comment: I made some custom adjustments, it seems to be working fine by now. I will re-check this thread if I stumble on a roadblock. Thanks again!

Comment: Uploading an image doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: awesome lib thank you. i have a small issue, the final editor value i get doesn't have the css (for example no text-align: center even though user clicked on align-center)

Comment: @omer https://angular-editor.kolkov.ru/ Is there a problem with this example?

Comment: No image image resizing...

Answer (score 8):

Thanks @Ronin for sharing your research. Here is my feedback on a couple I tested.

[NGX-EDITOR](https://github.com/Sibiraj-S/ngx-editor)

First I tried [ngx-editor](https://github.com/Sibiraj-S/ngx-editor) and was relatively easy to install and use. Only needed ngs-boostrap and fontAwesome as dependencies. Hoever the only drawback I found for my requirements was the adding link widget. This library does not remember the link that you have entered so if you want to change them you need to remove and re-add it. Another limitation was that one could not specify a max Length value.

[NGX-QUILL](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill)

I ended up using [ngx-quill](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill). It has a better way to deal with links as well as the ability to specify max-Length. It was also very easy to install:

```
npm install ngx-quill
npm install quill  // Needed for CSS styles

import { QuillModule } from 'ngx-quill'
import 'quill/dist/quill.core.css'
import 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,

    QuillModule
  ],
  ...
})
class YourModule { ... }
```

Comment: Current version of ngx-quill does not support parsing HTML <table> element. It is though under development. So far it works fine in All Browsers including IE11.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ng2-editor. It has many options to manage .

> https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor

Answer (score 2):

I use "[ngx-quill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-quill)" as a WYSIWYG Editor in my Angular4 project.

This is an Angular (>=2) component for rich text editor Quill

```
angular v4 - ngx-quill <=1.6.0
angular v5 - ngx-quill > 1.6.0
angular v6 - ngx-quill >= 3.0.0
```

- [demo-page](https://killercodemonkey.github.io/ngx-quill-example/)
  [tool bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqtnw.png)