# Change style/format of selected text - Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-directive

I'm creating forum and I want the forum to have an area for the user the enter the description, etc similar to what stackoverflow has. Is there's a tool already out there? if not, how can I format selected text in the textarea with angular.

```
<button (click)="boldSelectedText()">Bold Text</button>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
  At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free 
  tutorials in all web development technologies. 
</textarea>
```

In the picture below is a screenshot of how the one from SO looks like. If you see there a button to bold selected text.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/
good one for angular or you can google `wysiwyg editor for angular`

Comment: Thank you! I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176686/wysiwyg-editor-for-angular4

Comment: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html here's how to use the tool you mentioned in Angular

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the editor libraries for Angular. I would personally recommend ngx-editor.
Link: https://sibiraj-s.github.io/ngx-editor/additional-documentation/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

http://embed.plnkr.co/8F5nG9FJ6ZsuCtH8zrmH the exactly name is WYSWYG, try with ng-style or ng-class.

Comment: Any code necessary to make sense of the answer should be included as part of the answer. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52878518/edit) your answer and include any relevant code there.

Comment: You answer works. Yes, you are right that's how it's called, but your solution is using AngularJS not Angular.